# UILabel linebreak on other view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, uilabel

I have UIView which is container for 2 views: UILabel and UIImage. Lets say that UIIlabel is same size as container. If I add UIImage at some position in container, is it possible that text is shown  only in empty area where there is no image ?

Something like in word document when you place image, text breaks line whenever it intersects beggining of image. Is this possible in objective c ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iOS 7, there is a new framework named Text Kit. Working with Text Kit, you can simply add exclusion paths in UITextView which meet your question.

Here is a [Text Kit Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50151/text-kit-tutorial) by raywenderlich and some screen shot:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Too bad its only iOS 7, but will use anyway. Thanks.